# Set ansible_host in group variables

Tags: ansible

This may be a stupid idea but I have two identical playgrounds for my ansible script.

I want to create a playbook with a Inventory containing two groups and choose the ip from the host via group is this possible? I'm needing it because the frontend and backend needed the same host_vars in both groups but are different server.

host_vars:

frontend.yml ( in host_vars):

```
frontent_property=look good
```

backend .yml ( in host_vars):

```
backend_property=handle requests
```

group_vars:

integration.yml ( in group_vars):

```
integration_property=have fun
```

production.yml ( in group_vars):

```
production_property=do business
```

Inventory:

```
frontend
backend 

[integration]
frontend  ansible_host=10.0.0.5
backend    ansible_host=10.0.0.6

[production]
frontend  ansible_host=10.1.0.5
backend   ansible_host=10.1.0.6
```

Playbook:

```
- hosts: integration
  gather_facts: false
  tasks: 
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_host }}"
        
- hosts: production
  gather_facts: false
  tasks: 
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ ansible_host }}"
```

This didn't work (both are running against the integrations ips )- is there another solution to solve this?

I have found a solution but now I'm loosing the host_vars :

group_vars:
frontend.yml ( in group_vars):

```
frontent_property=look good
```

backend.yml ( in group_vars):

```
backend_property=handle requests
```

integration.yml ( in group_vars):

```
some_property=have fun
```

production.yml ( in group_vars):

```
some_property=do business
```

Inventory:

```
10.0.0.5
10.0.0.6
10.1.0.5
10.1.0.6

[frontend]
10.0.0.5
10.1.0.5

[backend]
10.0.0.6
10.1.0.6

[integration]
10.0.0.6
10.0.0.5  

[production]
10.1.0.5 
10.1.0.6
```

But its more likly that I made a mistake, because I'm not using the :children specifier (Group in Group) so I don't think that the group values from [backend] are accessible from the scope [integration]/production or am I wrong?

Comment: Why is it necessary to *"choose the ip from the host via group"*?

Comment: because I have hostvariables stick together to the hostname. I'll change the target without changing the hostvariables - is the bad practice? I'll try you snippet soon

Comment: If you want to *"change the target without changing the host-variables"* (which I understand as having common variables for all hosts) put the variables into the section [all:vars] (when ini-formatted inventory is used).

Comment: I have for every hosts custom variables. I'm using the host_vars and the within the folder contains a frontend.yml and the backend.yml with the custom variables.  frontend and backend are aliases

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct inventory

```yaml
10.0.0.5
10.0.0.6
10.1.0.5
10.1.0.6

[integration]
10.0.0.5 my_hostname=frontend
10.0.0.6 my_hostname=backend

[production]
10.1.0.5 my_hostname=frontend
10.1.0.6 my_hostname=backend
```

Comment: it seems like that my_hostname is only a custom variable. Is it possible to set aliases the same way with an other variable?